# How can I find all config entries for enabled payment or shipping methods and copy them to another store?

Tags: configuration, payment-methods, shipping-methods, core-config-data

I want to be able to export the enabled payment or shipping methods for a store, then import that into a new store, without overwriting any other configuration values. It's safe to assume that both stores use the same encryption key.

A typical use-case for this might be when trying to maintain an identical payment config across multiple Magento instances, or "merge" one store's payment methods into a second store, but I'm sure there are plenty of other uses.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this process, which unfortunately relies on a program called SequelPro (only runs on MacOS, and I'm a linux guy). This process is far from ideal, can't be automated, and is only being provided for reference.

1. Run this query to get the relevant values:

   `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path REGEXP (
       SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('^', REPLACE(path, '/active', '')) SEPARATOR '|') FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "payment/%/active" AND value=1`
   )
2. Select all the records, right click, then "Copy as SQL Insert"
3. Paste everything into a text editor, change `INSERT` to `REPLACE`, change the ID values to NULL (to create new auto_increment keys)
4. Copy and paste back into SequelPro, and run that query on the destination database to set those values